# Excel replace characters in string before and after 'x'

Tags: string, excel, substitution, string-substitution

Hello I have a column with strings (names of products) in it. 
Now these are formatted as *Name LenghtxWidth*, example Green box 20x30. Now I need to change the 20 with the 30 in this example so I get Green box 30x20, any ideas how I can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: You would like to do that without using VBA?

Comment: Yes, or excel formulas, as long as I get the result I'm looking for

Comment: @Jesse are the length and width always 2 digits? So no "100x50" or "5x10"?  If so, then this could be done easily with formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution that will work for you:

```
Option Explicit

Function Switch(r As Range) As String

Dim measurement As String
Dim firstPart As String
Dim secondPart As String

measurement = Right(r, Len(r) - InStrRev(r, " "))
secondPart = Right(measurement, Len(measurement) - InStr(1, measurement, "x"))
firstPart = Left(measurement, InStr(1, measurement, "x") - 1)
Switch = Left(r, InStrRev(r, " ") - 1) & " " & secondPart & "x" & firstPart

End Function
```

You can paste this in a regular module in the `VBE (Visual Basic Editor)` and use it as a regular function/formula. If your value is in cell A1 then type `=Switch(A1)` in cell B1. Hope it helps!

Comment: note that in the switch = ... the x must be between " ".

Comment: @Jesse Good eye! Thanks for bringing that to my attention! You know what happened was I originally had an `x` variable to find the `x` in `20x30' and realized I didn't need it. When I deleted the variable I failed to make `x` in the switch statement a string literal. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Yes I thought so, thanks for the answer this is what got me the solution to my problem in the end!

Comment: Not sure if you switched the hardcoded `Range("A1")` portions to the `r` variable - FYI.

Answer (score 4):

Here is both a formula solution, as well as a VBA solution using Regular Expressions:

**Formula**

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),A1)-1)&
MID(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),SEARCH("x",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)))+1,99)&
"x"&
LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),SEARCH("x",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1)
```

**UDF**

```
Option Explicit
Function RevWL(S As String)
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(\d+.?\d*)x(\d+.?\d*)"

'If L or W might start with a decimal point, and not a digit,
'Then change sPat to:  (\d*.?\d+)x(\d*.?\d+)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    RevWL = .Replace(S, "$2x$1")
End With

End Function
```

Here is an example of the kinds of data I tested with:

[image]

The Formula works by looking at the last space-separated substring which would be `LxW`, then reversing the portion after and before the `x`, then concatenating everything back together.

The regex pattern captures the two numbers (could be integers or decimals, so long as the start with an integer -- although that could be changed if needed), and reversing them.

Here is a more detailed explanation of the regex (and the replacement string) with links to a tutorial:

### (\d+.?\d*)x(\d+.?\d*)

```
(\d+.?\d*)x(\d+.?\d*)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d+.?\d*)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the character “x” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `x`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d+.?\d*)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

$2x$1

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`
- [Insert the character “x” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `x`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: I don't understand your UDF but that is really cool and a great solution. I need to learn that.

Comment: @Brian I will add a technical explanation of the Regex

Comment: Great detailed answer

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for that explanation, Ron! I stumbled upon this [site](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~chenx/reading/VBA/vb_regexp.html). Have you seen this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it is really easier to use VBA, but if you want only some formulas you can use some columns to split your text and then concatenate your cells.

Here is a little example:
[image]

Of course B1-4 are optional. It is here only to have something more readable, but you can do use only one formula

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1, SEARCH(" ",A1,1)-1)," ",RIGHT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)),LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)))-SEARCH("x",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)),1)),"x",LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)), SEARCH("x",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)),1)-1))
```

---

If you have **several spaces** in your names, you can use this formula that will search the last *space* in the text

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1, SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)," ",RIGHT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))))-SEARCH("x",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),1)),"x",LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))), SEARCH("x",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),1)-1))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can u maybe provide an example with the vba script? Since the above formulas doens't work when there are multiple spaces in the name, example Yellow Small Case 30x15 => Small Case 30x15

Comment: You can use this formula to get a name with several spaces `=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)`